# How to keep a C# Enum in sync with a table in database

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-3.5, enums

This is a somewhat simplified example (I changed it around to hide the actual code).
I have a database-powered app and a small tool that is being developed separately that is meant to work with the app. There is a table that defines an enumeration, but it could potentially change over time. Suppose some app (medical?) needed to track the sex of a person rather precisely.

`select * from sex order by id;`

```
id | mnemonic | description
0  | U        | Unknown sex
1  | M        | Male
2  | F        | Female
3  | T        | Trans-gender
```

And my `C# enum`:

```
public enum SexType
{
    /// <summary>Unknown sex.</summary>
    [Description("U")]
    Unknown = 0,

    /// <summary>Male sex.</summary>
    [Description("M")]
    Male = 1,

    /// <summary>Female sex.</summary>
    [Description("F")]
    Female = 2

    /// <summary>Trans-gender sex.</summary>
    [Description("T")]
    TransGender = 3,
}
```

Here I should not assume that the id is a continuous sequence; neither are these enums flags that can be combined, even though it might look that way.

Some of the logic is done in SQL; some is done in `C#` code. For instance, I might have a function:

```
// Here we get id for some record from the database.
public static void IsMaleOrFemale(int sexId)
{
    if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(SexType), sexId))
    {
        string message = String.Format("There is no sex type with id {0}.", 
            sexId);
        throw new ArgumentException(message, "sexId");
    }

    var sexType = (SexType) sexId;
    return sexType == SexType.Male || sexType == SexType.Female;
}
```

This can work fairly well as long as neither the table nor the enum definitions change. But the table might. I cannot rely on the id column or the mnemonic column maintaining their values. I think the best I can to is have a unit test which makes sure that the table is in sync with my definition of an enum. I am trying to match the value to id, and the description attribute to mnemonic column.

So, how to I get a list of all pairs (programmatically, in `C#`): `(0, "U"), (1, "M"), (2, "F"), (3, "T")` by looking at the `enum SexType`?

The idea is to tightly compare this ordered list with `select id, mnemonic from sex order by is asc;`.

Comment: Wow, I'd never thought to unit test that. I love that idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier if you just named the enum values U, M, F and T. If you did that, the `Enum` class's static methods do all the work for you.

Barring that, you need to use a bit of reflection to dig out the Description attributes

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<string, int>> GetEnumValuePairs(Type enumType)
{
    if(!enumType.IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    List<Tuple<string, int>> result = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();

    foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(enumType))
    {
        string fieldName = Enum.GetName(enumType, value);

        FieldInfo fieldInfo = enumType.GetField(fieldName);
        var descAttribute = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false).Where(a => a is DescriptionAttribute).Cast<DescriptionAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

        // ideally check if descAttribute is null here
        result.Add(Tuple.Create(descAttribute.Description, (int)value));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in the actual table there are about a dozen and having descriptive names does help.

Comment: Yeah that bit of reflection in my code is pulling the value out of the Description attributes, so the result is "Male", "Female", etc.

Answer (score 9):

Why not change SexType from an enum to a class (or Struct) and populate a List from your database at runtime?

Your struct (or class) would look something like this:

```
public struct SexType
{
  public string Type;
  public string Code;
  public int Value;
}
```

Then you could populate from your database a `List<SexType>` (or, if you're using EF, you could pull down a list of Entities of type SexType, or whatever your solution allows).

Presuming you're using Linq and EF, do eager loading when the application starts, and you should be good-to-go.

Comment: The difficulty with this approach is implementing the `IsMaleOrFemale` function based on that list. I do not know if ids will remain the same, if "M"/"F" will be renamed to "MA"/"FE", etc. With static enum + unit test I am able to make an assumption but then also test it.

Comment: Are you saying that the data in the table might actually change to MA/FE?  Presumably that would cause a problem no matter what you do- unless you don't really need the Enum to match the table, it just needs to have roughly-equivalent values...  Or am I missing something?

Comment: yes, there is a chance that an actual table (which is not about sex) might actually change to "MA"/"FE" or "MALE"/"FEMALE". I might still use the struct, but I need extra array that stores all records, plus code + data st. which remembers the mapping and then a unit test which makes sure that everything is in sync. If the test passes I am good. if the test fails fails - then I will need to rewrite some code.

Comment: Obviously YMMV- but at every organization where I've worked that needed something similar (I'm guessing you're in health care in some form) we set up the ANSI values for Sex in their own table, and anything that referenced sex either used a reference to that table (Sex = 1) for instance, instead of (Sex = "MALE"), or grabbed the value straight from that table.  Not sure if that's an option for you, though.

Answer (score 8):

Check out [Tangible T4Editor](http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/).

I use it to do just that.

Install it and then add this file to your project ([more information on this blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/generate-enum-of-database-lookup-table.html)):

**EnumGenerator.ttinclude**

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension=".generated.cs" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>
<#  
    string tableName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Host.TemplateFile);
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile);
    string columnId = "ID";
    string columnName = "NAME";
    string connectionString = "[your connection string]";
#>
using System; 
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;  

namespace Your.NameSpace.Enums
{     
    /// <summary>
    /// <#= tableName #> auto generated enumeration
    /// </summary>
    [GeneratedCode("TextTemplatingFileGenerator", "10")]
    public enum <#= tableName #>
    { 
<#
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    string command = string.Format("select {0}, {1} from {2} order by {0}", columnId, columnName, tableName);
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(command, conn);

    conn.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
    bool loop = reader.Read(); 

    while(loop)
    { 
#>
        /// <summary>
        /// <#= reader[columnName] #> configuration setting.
        /// </summary>
        <#= reader[columnName] #> = <#= reader[columnId] #><# loop = reader.Read(); #><#= loop ? ",\r\n" : string.Empty #> 
<#  } 
#>  }
} 
<#+     private string Pascalize(object value)
        {
            Regex rx = new Regex(@"(?:^|[^a-zA-Z]+)(?<first>[a-zA-Z])(?<reminder>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)");
            return rx.Replace(value.ToString(), m => m.Groups["first"].ToString().ToUpper() + m.Groups["reminder"].ToString().ToLower());
        }      

        private string GetSubNamespace()
        {
            Regex rx = new Regex(@"(?:.+Services\s)");
            string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile);
            return rx.Replace(path, string.Empty).Replace("\\", ".");
        }
#>
```

(fill in the namespace of your class and the connection string)

Then, you can just add a blank TT file with a single line <#@ include file="EnumGenerator.ttinclude" #>`. The name of this file should be identical to the table's name, and the columns of this table must be named "ID" and "NAME" unless you change it in the enum generator class.

Whenever you save the TT file, the Enum will be auto generated.

Comment: Hm ... this looks intriguing. So, does a free edition handle this, or would I need to buy a PRO license?

Answer (score 5):

```
var choices = Enumerable.Zip(
    Enum.GetNames(typeof(SexType)),
    Enum.GetValues(typeof(SexType)).Cast<SexType>(),
    (name, value) => Tuple.Create(name, value));
```

Comment: Thanks, almost there! One thing that I need to be different is that I would like to get an array of description attributes rather than names of the enum types.

Comment: To the editor: please don't do that.  The documentation for `GetNames` and `GetValues` makes it very clear that they already return the values and names in order of the enum values, so it's unnecessary to order it here.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [T4 Text Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) which would dynamically generate the enumeration for you when the template is processed (on save and/or build).

Then, this template (which includes C# code) will generate the enumeration definition for you into a .cs file based on the contents of your database.

Of course, it means you will have to have access to a database at save/compile time, but this is the only way to guarantee that these two are in line at compile time.

At runtime, you might want to perform a one-time check against the database to make sure that the enumeration and the values in the database are in line.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Tuple<int, string>> pairs = new List<Tuple<int,string>>();
     Type enumType = typeof(SexType);
     foreach (SexType enumValue in Enum.GetValues(enumType))
     {
        var customAttributes = enumType.GetField(Enum.GetName(enumType, enumValue)).
           GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        DescriptionAttribute descriptionAttribute = 
           (DescriptionAttribute)customAttributes.FirstOrDefault(attr => 
              attr is DescriptionAttribute);

        if (descriptionAttribute != null)
           pairs.Add(new Tuple<int, string>((int)enumValue, descriptionAttribute.Description));
     }
```